# how to set facebook Requests Dialog height?

Tags: facebook

I had a problem regrading my Requests Dialog height. My Requests Dialog work very well, but the problem is the Requests Dialog box height very short.

Here is my Requests Dialog box:

[image]

here is my app: http://apps.facebook.com/christmas_testing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194725433940802